# 'server was unable to allocate from the system nonpaged pool' error

Tags: windows-server-2000

Currently users at my company are unable to access their home folder (or any folder on our domain controller).  I am working remotely and cant physically access the machine until tomorrow morning, but I can access it with RDC.

When I attempt to ping other machines on our network from the machine in question (connected with RDC), I immediately get the error

> PING: transmit failed.  error code 1450.

Event Viewer is full of 2019 errors:

> The server was unable to allocate from the system nonpaged pool because the pool was empty

Does anyone have experience with this specific issue?  I have found some info with Google, but would like to hear what the pros at SF have top say.

This is a Windows 2000 server.

Answer (score 1):

If the system is not completely borked, you may be able to install the Windows debugger, and then you can run a kernel debug (File > Kernel Debug> Local tab), and run the command "!vm" - that will give you a listing of the memory allocations and usage.  The "!poolused 4" command will show you the details of the various driver usage, sorted by paged pool consumed.

If you cannot do that, you may want to try forcing a crash of the server, and get a memory dump for analysis.  You may be able to run Sysinternals PSKILL to terminate the system's CSRSS process to force a crash.  This would be the csrss process with the lowest process id number.

http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/Devtools/Debugging/default.mspx

Comment: Whenever a solution starts out with 'if the system is not completely borked' you know its going to be a long week.  I am reading this and checking out your link now.  Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

There must be a memory leak (or a handle leak) that makes the non-paged memory pool empty. You can find the non-paged pool size in the task manager. As Greg Askew said you can analyze the memory with WinDbg tool.